# Replace String with numbers starting a as 1 to z as 26

Tags: string, powershell, replace

I have a string `"Powershell"`

Need to replace with numbers based on its alphabetic values (that is, each letter should be preceded by its index in the alphabet).

So the expected output should be like

`16(P)15(o)` and so on.

Please need some idea on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `[Regex]::Replace()` method - it can take a scriptblock to compute the substitution value:

```
$string = 'Powershell'
$pattern = '[a-zA-Z]'
$substitution = {
  param($Match)

  return "$(-96 + $Match.Value.ToLower()[0])($($Match.Value))"
}

[regex]::Replace($string, $pattern, $substitution)
```

Resulting in the string:

```
16(P)15(o)23(w)5(e)18(r)19(s)8(h)5(e)12(l)12(l)
```

---

If you're using PowerShell 6.2 or newer, this feature is also supported by the `-replace` operator:

```
$string = 'Powershell'
$pattern = '[a-zA-Z]'
$substitution = {
  return "$(-96 + $_.Value.ToLower()[0])($($_.Value))"
}

$string -replace $pattern,$substitution
```